# Drag down Series

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have an Excel workbook with multiple Sheets month wise(i.e Jan, Feb, March).

Data are arranged like
[image]

January in separate sheet and February in Separate sheet.

Now in summary sheet I would like to add = `JanA3+`FebA3+`MarchA3
And the next entry in summary will be    =  JanA6+`FebA6+`MarchA6

When I drag that formula in Summary Sheet, it is not coming automatically.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question/doubt clearly...
Are you trying to say:
You've used the formula **=Jan!A3+Feb!A3+Mar!A3** in summary sheet Cell A3...but you are not able to use the same formula for Cell A6?

Comment: @ravishchhabra: I have used that formula in cell AA1. In AA2 cell I need =Jan!A6+Feb!A6+Mar!A6....If I drag it then it is not filling automatically..

Comment: If you copy a formula from one cell to another cell...the cell references move by the same amount...so if you've used this formula in AA1...then if you copy and paste the formula in AA2...you'll get the sum for =Jan!A4+Feb!A4+Mar!A4
If you paste this formula in AA4 you'll get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell excel to change the reference by 3 rows when you only move the formula one row.

You can write a macro to do this or you can fill the formula down until you get the result you want and then delete the cells between and shift the cells up.  The reference will remain as you want.